# Pyppeteer - timeout = 1000 ms but page.goto still hangs forever

Tags: python-asyncio, pyppeteer

I noticed that one `url` makes `pyppeteer` hang forever. That's weird because I've set `timeout`. Do you know where is the problem? Or is it `asyncio` problem?

```
async def test():
    url = 'https://ig.com.br/'
    browser = await launch(headless=True)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(1000)
    await page.setUserAgent(fake_useragent.UserAgent().random)
    await page.goto(url, {'waitUntil': 'networkidle0','timeout':1000})
    await browser.close()

asyncio.run(test())
```

Other websites work well - it timeouts because the timeout value is too small. But this website makes it hang forever.

Do you know why? I want to make sure that any website will either be fetched under 20 seconds or raise error.